# How reduce number of xlims?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I want to reduce the  xlim label because i'm using datetime information and that take long space of the xlim. The problem it's when i want to read that

So i need some like to scale that, i think

```
dates = pd.read_csv("EURUSDtest.csv")
dates = dates["Date"]+" " + dates["Time"]
plt.title("EUR/USD")
plt.plot(dates, data_pred)
plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.tick_params(labelsize=10)
plt.plot(forecasting)
```

The problem...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: You need to convert the dates column to pandas datetime type by calling `pd.to_datetime`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# To reproduce the issue you have lets create a date column as string
df = pd.DataFrame({"Dates":pd.date_range(start='2018-1-1', end='2019-1-1', freq='15MIN').strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H-%M-%S")})
# Convert the date string to date type 
df["Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dates"])
# Add column to assign some dummy values
df = df.assign(VAL=np.linspace(10, 110, len(df)))
# Plot the graph
# Now the graph automatically adjusts the XLIM based on the size of the graph
plt.title("eur/usd")
plt.plot(df["Dates"], df["VAL"])
plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
plt.show()
```

### However if you need to further control xlim to your needs you need to go through matplotlib tutorials.

[image]